# I am not able to view DVR remotely even after portforwarding in the router

Tags: router

I noticed that when I am connecting 3G dongle to router and then doing the port forwarding of the DVR ports in the router, I am not able to view DVR remotely.

I noticed that the IP, I am getting in the router web page is different when checking with [“what’s my IP”](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&safe=off&q=what+is+my+ip) via Google is different. So suggest me if there is any other setting needs to be done for 3G data cards on router as I am not able to view DVR remotely.

Comment: Does the IP address you are trying to connect to remotely look like 192.168.1.1? If so, you are connecting to the wrong one. Search on Google for `what is my ip` and it will tell you the correct address you need to use.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.I am trying to coonect remotely through DDNS and also the DDNS sttings has been properly configured.Jake - But the external IP which I am getting from Whats my IP is also not pinging and while cheking whether the ports are forwarded are not on canyouseeme.org they are not showing open.Also to note you that the external IP which i am getting on Router's web page in WAN connections is also different than Whats my ip address.Is there anything we need to do while configuring the 3g dongle on the router?